# Drupal 7 Views merging

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm recently starting to develop with Drupal, reading and learning all I can.

I'm trying to make a "Team" page. I have a custom content type called "Team Member" with: Name, Photograph, Bio, and Role (Coordinator or Speaker). I added my team members and now I want to write a view (on /team) that lists all of my members. The problem is, the two kinds of members (coordinators of speakers) have slightly different layouts and, also, I want to have a  before each type.

Something like this:

```
<h1>Team</h1>
   <h2>Coordinators</h2>
   <ul>...Coordinators here...</ul>

   <h2>Speakers</h2>
   <ul>...Speakers here...</ul>
```

Any ideas how to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Views allows you to add attachments (see http://drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2009/07/using-views-relationships-arguments-attachments) which essentially lets you combine two or more views in one.

Comment: I ended up using Format > Settings > Grouping Field = Content:Role.
Is like GROUP BY on SQL! 
But I'll definitely check into your approach. Thanks!